# How to pivot table by month and display top 10 by total amount only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, top-n

I have a dynamic dataset that returns data from today and a year back. 
How can I pivot this data and return only top 10 `Description` by `NetWrittenPremium`?

I know how to perform static pivot, but confused how would I do it in this case.

```
        ;with cte_TopClasses
    AS  ( 
            SELECT      
                        b.MonthNum,
                        b.YearNum,
                        GovClassCode + ' - ' + dda.GovClassDesc as Description,
                        ISNULL(SUM(Premium),0) as NetWrittenPremium 
            FROM        tblCalendar b 
            LEFT JOIN   ProductionReportMetrics prm ON b.YearNum = Year(prm.EffectiveDate) AND b.MonthNum=Month(prm.EffectiveDate) AND  CompanyLine = 'Arch Insurance Company'
            LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[Dynamic_Data_ArchWC] dda ON prm.QuoteGUID = dda.QuoteGuid    
            WHERE       
                        ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 and b.MonthNum >= MONTH(GETDATE())+1 ) OR 
                        ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE()) and b.MonthNum <= MONTH(GETDATE()) )      
            GROUP BY    b.YearNum ,
                        b.MonthNum, 
                        GovClassCode,   
                        dda.GovClassDesc
        )
   --here I want to pivot it
    select *
    from cte_TopClasses
```

Current result is 128 records.

[image]

And desirable result would be something like that:

[image]

@Nico
It should be like that:

[image]

Yours is very close, just shift to 1 month ahead.

[image]

Comment: is your starting month always October?

Comment: No, that is the problem. Its dynamic. Its always starts from `GETDATE()` till 12 months back.

Comment: I don't see what pivoting has to do with this problem.

Comment: I do not understand the desired result. It should be for one year?

Comment: it should be for one year back from today. Lets say if we run report in Friday Sep 8, 2017, then it should be  from October 1, 2016 till Sep 30,2017. Dates in `WHERE` clause making it happen.

Comment: @Oleg please let me know where does my answer go wrong, and i can't see the day number, too. ty in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's somewhat complicated. More information about dynamic pivot, you can check [this post](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1011591/Dynamic-Pivot-Query-in-SQL-Server).

```
--begin get the ordered month name of past one year
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @startMonth AS INT

--line 1
SET @startMonth=MONTH(GETDATE())+1

WHILE(@startMonth<=12)
BEGIN 
  SET @cols= COALESCE(@cols,'')+'['+CAST(@startMonth AS varchar)+'],';
  SET @startMonth=@startMonth+1;
END

--line 2
SET @startMonth=MONTH(GETDATE())+1

DECLARE @countFlag INT
SET @countFlag=0

WHILE(@startMonth>1)
BEGIN 
  SET @countFlag=@countFlag+1;
  SET @cols= COALESCE(@cols,'')+'['+CAST(@countFlag AS varchar)+'],';
  SET @startMonth=@startMonth-1;
END

SET @cols=SUBSTRING(@cols,1,LEN(@cols)-1)
-- end

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols=REPLACE(@cols,'10','October');
SET @cols=REPLACE(@cols,'11','November');
SET @cols=REPLACE(@cols,'12','December');
SET @cols=REPLACE(@cols,'1','January');
SET @cols=REPLACE(@cols,'2','February');
SET @cols=REPLACE(@cols,'3','March');
SET @cols=REPLACE(@cols,'4','April');
SET @cols=REPLACE(@cols,'5','May');
SET @cols=REPLACE(@cols,'6','June');
SET @cols=REPLACE(@cols,'7','July');
SET @cols=REPLACE(@cols,'8','August');
SET @cols=REPLACE(@cols,'9','September');

SET @query = '

SELECT 
    TOP 10
    *,
    ISNULL([October],0)+ISNULL([November],0)+ISNULL([December],0)+ISNULL([January],0)+ISNULL([February],0)+ISNULL([March],0)+ISNULL([April],0)+ISNULL([May],0)+ISNULL([June],0)+ISNULL([July],0)+ISNULL([August],0)+ISNULL([September],0) AS Total
FROM 
(
    SELECT DateName(month, DateAdd(month, MonthNum, -1))  AS [MonthName],[Description],SUM(NetWrittenPremium) AS SubTotal FROM dbo.cte_TopClasses WHERE ((YearNum-YEAR(GETDATE()))*12+MonthNum-MONTH(GETDATE()))>-12 AND ((YearNum-YEAR(GETDATE()))*12+MonthNum-MONTH(GETDATE()))<=0 GROUP BY [MonthNum],[Description]
) AS source
PIVOT
(
    SUM(SubTotal)
    FOR MonthName
    IN (' + @cols + ')
) AS pvtMonth
ORDER BY Total
'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Comment: Nico, sorry for late respond. I tried to achieve this in SSRS, but apparently the only way to do it is to massage the query. Its amazing, yours is works, the only thing it starts from September 2016 and ends up August 2017. Is any chance to make it starting from October 2016 and ending it in September 2017? I will post an update. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Oleg well, i make it starting from October 2016 by adding 1 to the 'currentMonth', try it.

Comment: Sorry, disregard my above comment.  If I change `SET @currentMonth=MONTH(GETDATE())+1` then it gives me an error `Invalid column name 'September'`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now I just need to create a tablix in SSRS with those dynamic columns. Thanks and sorry for late respond.