# Can I make a tablix report in SSRS from dynamically pivoted table?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

The result of my query is pivoted table that displays 12 months back starting from current month and total amount. Months are dynamic, so in October the first column in a table will be November and the last one will be October (current one).

[image]

How can I create simple tablix or matrix using this result set? My main concern is how to make dynamic Month name in a tablix?

Is that even possible?

[image]
 UPDATE:

I rename columns as values from 1 to 12. But when I try to write an expression fro October like: `=Month(Today()) - CInt(Fields!ID10.Value)` its just giving me a current month number. 
What am I missing?

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Data in table Calendar structured like this:

[image]

So I modified the query:

```
  DECLARE @CurrentMonth DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101');
--print @CurrentMonth

SELECT 
    M_00 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 0 THEN 1 END),
    M_01 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 1 THEN 1 END),
    M_02 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 2 THEN 1 END),
    M_03 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 3 THEN 1 END),
    M_04 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 4 THEN 1 END),
    M_05 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 5 THEN 1 END),
    M_06 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 6 THEN 1 END),
    M_07 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 7 THEN 1 END),
    M_08 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 8 THEN 1 END),
    M_09 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 9 THEN 1 END),
    M_10 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 10 THEN 1 END),
    M_11 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 11 THEN 1 END)
FROM 
    dbo.tblCalendar c
        /* changed "YearNum, MonthNum"  instead of "(YEAR(c.dt), MONTH(c.dt)" */
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (DATEFROMPARTS(YearNum, MonthNum, 1)) ) fom (FirstOfMonth)
WHERE 
    /* changed c.MonthNum instead of c.dt */
    c.MonthNum >= MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -11, @CurrentMonth))
    /* changed c.MonthNum instead of c.dt */
    AND c.MonthNum < MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @CurrentMonth));
```

Is that correct?

Sorry, here I got confused. The idea is not to use dynamic sql at all?
just use my query, which is:

```
;WITH cte_TopClasses
AS  ( 
SELECT
        c.YearNum,
        c.MonthNum,
        DD.ClassCode,
        ISNULL(SUM(prm.Premium),0) as NetWrittenPremium
FROM    tblCalendar c
LEFT JOIN  ProductionReportMetrics prm ON c.YearNum = YEAR(prm.EffectiveDate) and c.MonthNum = MONTH(prm.EffectiveDate) 
           AND CompanyGUID = '18E04C99-D796-4CFA-B1E7-28328321C8AD'      
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Dynamic_Data_GLUnitedSpecialty] DD on prm.QuoteGUID = DD.QuoteGuid 
WHERE   ( c.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 and c.MonthNum >= MONTH(GETDATE())+1 ) OR 
        ( c.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE()) and c.MonthNum <= MONTH(GETDATE()) ) 
GROUP BY    c.YearNum,
            c.MonthNum,
            DD.ClassCode        
    ) 

select * from cte_TopClasses
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe the table names in the datasource need to be static as the schema is saved. With that said, you can name the columns in SSRS based on a function around the current month. So you could have the dataset return the columns always as 11 to 0, and have SSRS dynamically name the tablix columns as current month minus the column name.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I did that but still got confused. I updated question.

Answer (score 1):

SSRS requires a fixed set of input columns, making dynamic piviot queries completely incompatible. Bring the data into SSRS unpivoted and let SSRS do it pivot on a matrix.

Edit... Using non-dynamic sql...

Do something along these lines...

```
DECLARE @CurrentMonth DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101');

SELECT 
    M_00 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 0 THEN 1 END),
    M_01 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 1 THEN 1 END),
    M_02 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 2 THEN 1 END),
    M_03 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 3 THEN 1 END),
    M_04 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 4 THEN 1 END),
    M_05 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 5 THEN 1 END),
    M_06 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 6 THEN 1 END),
    M_07 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 7 THEN 1 END),
    M_08 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 8 THEN 1 END),
    M_09 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 9 THEN 1 END),
    M_10 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 10 THEN 1 END),
    M_11 = COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fom.FirstOfMonth, @CurrentMonth) = 11 THEN 1 END)
FROM 
    dbo.Calendar c
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(c.dt), MONTH(c.dt), 1)) ) fom (FirstOfMonth)
WHERE 
    c.dt >= DATEADD(MONTH, -11, @CurrentMonth)
    AND c.dt < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @CurrentMonth);
```

Query output...

```
M_00        M_01        M_02        M_03        M_04        M_05        M_06        M_07        M_08        M_09        M_10        M_11
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
30          31          31          30          31          30          31          28          31          31          30          31
```

The idea is that the data in the columns cycles columns as the months progress but the column names always remain the same... So that it's always playing nice with SSRS.

Then, back in SSRS, rather than display the headers from the query, use a formula expression. Something like

```
=MonthName(month(Now()))
=MonthName(month(Now()) + 1)
=MonthName(month(Now()) + 2)
=MonthName(month(Now()) + 3)
...
```

Comment: the whole reason why I am doing such workaround is because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064690/how-to-pivot-table-by-month-and-display-top-10-by-total-amount-only

Comment: @Oleg - You don't need dynamic sql for this at all. I'll update my answer with a better explanation in a few mins...

Comment: @Oleg - What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL 2012 and Visual Studio 2010. Thanks

Comment: please let me know if you need any more information

Comment: @Oleg - Take a look at the edited answer. Let me know if you have questions.